# Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable. Show $(EX)(E\frac{1}{X})\geq 1$

Tags: probability, integration, expected-value

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable. Show $(EX)(E\frac{1}{X})\geq 1$. What does this say about the correlation between $X$ and $\frac{1}{X}$.

Further show that if $f,g$ are positive borel measurable functions  such that $f(x)g(x)\geq1$ then $Ef(X)Eg(X)\geq 1$

I suppose I could start with proving the second part of the question and then prove the first part as a consequence.

I know I'm going to ultimately use Holder's inequality for this one, but I'm struggling to clear the $p$ and $q$ when I integrate $$1=\int_\Omega 1 dP\leq \int_\Omega f(X)g(X) dP\leq \left(\int_\Omega f(X)^pdP\right)^{1/p}\left(\int_\Omega g(X)^qdP\right)^{1/q}$$

Is the product of those integrals at the end less than or equal to $$\left(\int_\Omega f(X)dP\right)\left(\int_\Omega g(X)dP\right)?$$

If so, how could I prove this?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: The first statement also immediately follows from [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality):


$$ E[x]\cdot E[1/x] \ge E[x] \cdot 1/E[x] = 1 $$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(X)g(X)\geqslant 1\iff \sqrt{f(X)g(X)}\geqslant 1$, therefore the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality give us

$$
1= \left(\int_{\Omega }1\mathop{}\!d P\right)^2\leqslant \left(\int_{\Omega }\sqrt{f(X)g(X)}\mathop{}\!d P\right)^2\leqslant \left(\int_{\Omega }f(X)\mathop{}\!d P\right)\left(\int_{\Omega }g(X)\mathop{}\!d P\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Jensen's inequality and the fact that $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$.

Jensen's inequality implies:

$$\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[X]} \leq \mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{X}],$$
which immediately solves the first part. For the second part we can again use Jensen's inequality to state, that
$$\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[g(X)]} \leq \mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{g(X)}]\leq \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$$
and conclude, that $1 \leq \mathbb{E}[g(X)] \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$.

Remark: Technically you would need to handle the cases $\mathbb{E}[X] = \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[g(X)] = \infty$ separately, but the statements are quite easy to verify in these cases.